# OpenCart - Want to add comments in invoice if order status is shipped

Tags: php, opencart

I tried a lot but was not successful.

In opencart order admin -> Any order -> History.

There we see below fields:

1. Order Status (processing, processed, shipped etc etc)
2. Notify customer
3. Comments

**Problem:**

As of now **only customer comments** are published when we click PRINT INVOICE (if customer comments are present)

Code for this in order_invoice.tpl (admin\view\template\sale)

```
         <?php if ($order['comment']) { ?>
  <table class="comment">
    <tr class="heading">
      <td><b><?php echo $column_comment; ?></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $order['comment']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I want to also show comments when admin select "Shipped" in order status.

**If order_status=shipped then show comments by admin in order_invoice.tpl**

Because when admin selects SHIPPED in order status and fills tracking number in comments, TRACKING NUMBER thus will be visible in INVOICE which will help customers to retain proof of tracking as well.

I think in opencart there are two variables **order_status** and **order_status_id**

I do not know the exact format and linking of these ...Could you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

First amend the data array in the controller (/admin/controller/sale/order.php) to add the order_status_id and the admin comments / histories:

```
$this->data['orders'][] = array(
  'order_id'             => $order_id,
  'invoice_no'         => $invoice_no,
  'date_added'         => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($order_info['date_added'])),
  'store_name'         => $order_info['store_name'],
  'store_url'          => rtrim($order_info['store_url'], '/'),
  'store_address'      => nl2br($store_address),
  'store_email'        => $store_email,
  'store_telephone'    => $store_telephone,
  'store_fax'          => $store_fax,
  'email'              => $order_info['email'],
  'telephone'          => $order_info['telephone'],
  'shipping_address'   => $shipping_address,
  'shipping_method'    => $order_info['shipping_method'],
  'payment_address'    => $payment_address,
  'payment_company_id' => $order_info['payment_company_id'],
  'payment_tax_id'     => $order_info['payment_tax_id'],
  'payment_method'     => $order_info['payment_method'],
  'product'            => $product_data,
  'voucher'            => $voucher_data,
  'total'              => $total_data,
  'comment'            => nl2br($order_info['comment']),
  'status'             => $order_info['order_status_id'],
  'admin_comments'     => $this->model_sale_order->getOrderHistories($order_id)
);
```

Then right at the end of the order_invoice.tpl view you can add this:

```
  <?php if ($order['status'] == 3) { ?>
  <table class="comment">
    <tr class="heading">
      <td><b><?php echo $column_comment; ?></b></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($order['admin_comments'] as $admin_comment) { ?>
        <?php if ($admin_comment['status'] == 'Shipped') { ?>
           <tr>
                <td><?php echo $admin_comment['comment']; ?></td>
           </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

order_status_id == 3 being shipped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. While it worked for order status = shipped, but if order status = shipped, it is also displaying previous comments for that particular order.

Suppose 

As of now Order_status = shipped for order XYZ. Previous status of order XYZ
(Processing : Processing comments)
(Processed  : Processed comments)
(Shipped: Shipping comments)
.I just want to Only show shipping comments for XYZ when its order status will be marked as shipped.

As of now its showing all 3 processing comments, processed comments, shipping comments for order_status=shipped orders.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried the above code. Its showing only text: Comments:. But actual admin comments are not getting displayed for which order status is shipped. Could you pls relook. Thanks

Comment: could you try the updated code for order_invoice.tpl and post back what is output

Comment: odd outputs with strings...-> Comment
[notify] => 1 ) Array ( [date_added] => 2014-03-14 10:28:18 [status] => Shipped [comment] => EP123456789OK [notify] => 1 )
Fraud Action: review
Is International: true
Transaction Response Message: The transaction is successful
Transaction Response Code: SUCCESS
Transaction Status: SUCCESS
Array ( [date_added] => 2014-03-14 10:26:24 [status] => Processing [comment] => Transaction Id: PZT14031415545524814

.........first its showing order_status=shipped comments, than other comments

Comment: Many many thanks jx12345...you said that should work...it worked..:-)

Comment: This is indeed solved..but it creates some error in admin order...when i am posting a new comment with any status update, it shows the blank comment form (only, as if a new page) again when i click add history..Comment is also getting published..but the original working was: when i click on add history, it shows me created comment above and below it shows the form (comment form)..as i know we have not done any working modification in order.php, so why this admin functionality is getting impacted..?? thanks

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your problem (if i understand correctly - you can no longer see past comments in the history section) I can still see them ok on my installation with the changes that we have made - perhaps the changes are conflicting with other changes specific to your system?

Comment: Yes you may be right. I have replaced with the original file including above changes...Semms working fine as of now.